# Burninate [this] tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I have just come across a question using the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) tag. This can refer in so many different languages I don't feel it adds any value to the questions, there are currently just over 4,000 questions tagged with it, ranging from PHP, jQuery, React, TypeScript and many many more.

Is it possible to start to burninate the tag?

Comment: Since it contains that many question, the effort to bruniate is huge, so we need to evaluate if `this` tag do damage (hence generates off-topic questions ecc). My humble evaluation is that it's probably of no use, but also it does not really do any damage, so I will not put in hours of reviewing to remove it, you can also read this for more information about when to burniate https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191

Comment: [Here is a breakdown of the tags that use the `this` tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/651496/852451/)

Comment: @PetterFriberg I read that article, and several of those points apply here. If you downvote, could you expand on why.

Comment: @gunr2171 As per that data, [tag:this] could be related to anything, therefore surely it's a terrible tag to have?

Comment: I do not think it's a good idea to burninate. Questions often fall under the scope of `this`, and is often properly paired with the language tag in question. If it's alone or improperly tagged (`this` isn't relevant at all), then the question needs to be edited. But since `this` differs widely in languages, it's a good tag to have when used correctly.

Comment: @Ian no downvote, since I love people who try to improve SO posting on meta, but also no upvote since in this case I can't see the effort vs benefit.  Hence I think we should invest our reviewer time on other stuff.

Comment: 'Often fall under the scope of [tag:this]', shouldn't [tag:scope] be a better tag? I can't think of any problem that doesn't revolve around the scope when referring to `this`

Comment: @Ian atleast in js there is a difference between `this` context and `scope` (lexical and block) of a variable..

Comment: Is this even homogeneous in every language? Like string, list, objects, arrays, etc.?

Comment: @Braiam It can be different in various languages, most point towards scoping and objects.

Answer (score 2):

It should exist I think. Because `this` has some value in many languages. In JavaScript and jQuery `this` has a great value when dealing with Objects.

If a user has to ask something about jQuery's this element, then the tag should be used.

Also in many languages, when dealing with Objects, `this` has a great value

Comment: If the problem revolves around `this` being a problem, then surely that would come under `scope`? `this` adds no value to the question.